# Positioning absolute inside relative, inside fixed, inside absolute - broken in IE7

Tags: css, css-position

I am working on an existing web app, I am tasked with making it working IE7.  It works fine in IE8, FF, etc.

Example of structure:

```
<div id="page">    ------------- absolute position
 <div id="shell">  -------------  static position
   <div id="outer">   ------------  fixed position
      <div id="inner">  ------------  relative position
          <h1>My Title</h1>  ------------ absolute position
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem in IE 7 is the H1 is no here on the screen.  If I change it to relative, it shows up kind of close to where it needs to be.  I suspect the issue has something to do with having abs in rel in fixed, etc but I dont want to start trying combos before I know the rules.

So if there are any obvious rules being violated here as regards IE 7, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Your asking alot for internet explorer really arnt you ha

Comment: Could you add the CSS? Also `fixed` will be "loose" from its parent elements as it will always refer to the viewport.

Comment: After further inspection I have decided to save the various page content but redo the main site structure from scratch because it is just such a horrific mess.  Thank you for your time.